# Remote job for Swiss employer but stay in Germany

Tags: visa, germany

Wish to know what kind of visa or process can allow me to take this ahead:

- I finished my masters in Berlin between 2017- 2020
- Worked as a working student in Germany
- Worked as a freelancer in Germany
- My 18 month job search visa after Masters in Germany expires in Dec
- Possibility of an offer from a Swiss company for a remote position
- Want to continue to stay in Germany.

Is there any way to get this to work?

Assuming :

- The Swiss company doesnt have a German entity.
- I don´t marry a Swiss/EU national.

Comment: I assume you are not an EU citizen yourself, is that correct? I doubt it's possible in that case.

Comment: What's the rationale for wanting to stay in Germany instead of moving to Switzerland? 
 Are you pursuing citizenship in Germany?  It takes 8 years, but I believe it's shortened to 7 if you take an integration course.  So if you arrived in 2017, and if you took the integration course, you'd be eligible three years from now.  Then as an EU citizen, you'd have the right to live and work anywhere in the EU...and you'd also have the right to live and/or work in Switzerland, even though it's not part of the EU.